# Hardening Ubuntu with Docker.io

Tags: ubuntu, chef, docker, provisioning, hardening

I am new to Docker so please keep in mind.

The old way:

1. Create cloud instance
2. Add Ubuntu OS
3. Provision / harden Linux via Chef
4. Develop app locally
5. Deploy via Capistrano or some other deployment tool

The docker way:

1. Create cloud instance
2. Add Ubuntu OS
3. ???

Do I harden Linux first and then save it to a Docker image?  Or do I create a Docker container and then harden it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that both apply. Divide the hardening process in two steps:

- A baseline, common hardening that all images should enforce regardless their final use.
- Specific configuration targeting an application (a database, a web server, ...)

Create a hardened image from your OS of choice and use a local registry to store it.

You can have [`dockerfiles`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder) targeting specific applications that build [`FROM`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#from) the hardened image and apply further restrictions if needed.